# grails easygrid 1.4.6 installation

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to use the easygrid plugin in grails. Grails downloads all the plugins, but this one fails with following message. I tried with both the grails 2.3.6 and 2.3.7 versions as well as easygrid 1.4.5 and 1.4.6

```
Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for   
org.grails.plugins:easygrid:zip:1.4.6 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Thanks

Comment: Didn't see a problem installing this plugin in a Grails 2.3.7 app. Make sure it is not behind a firewall.

Comment: @dmahapatro The rest of the plugins are getting downloaded fine.

Comment: Yea, but this plugin might be pulling dependencies which may raise the flag. On a side note, do you have `inherits true` mentioned in `BuildConfig`.?

Comment: yes, inherits under repositories is set to true.

Comment: ok got it to work. BuildConfig file had (compile ':cache:1.1.1'). so once I changed it to double quotes, all the plugins declared after that are getting downloaded and installed fine.